# How to avoid empty space charactor in C++ with MFC

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc

I am crating simple web request using C++ MFC.Get the sample code from [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/165298) site.

```
CString strHeaders =_T("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
CString strFormData = _T("name=John+Doe&userid=hithere&other=P%26Q");
    

CInternetSession session;
CHttpConnection* pConnection =session.GetHttpConnection(_T("localhost:89"));
CHttpFile* pFile =  pConnection->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_POST,_T("FormActionHere"));
BOOL result = pFile->SendRequest(strHeaders, (LPVOID)(LPCVOID)strFormData, strFormData.GetLength());
```

**I know `LPCVOID` is A pointer to a null-terminated string.**

When I used character set as `Use Unicode Character Set` in project properties it's send the parameter with null terminated character (empty space character).

[image]

But when I used character set as `Use Multi-Byte Character Set` it's displayed correctly without any spaces.

How to send this web request without this null terminate characters with using `Use Unicode Character Set` ?

Comment: Convert your wide character strings to UTF-8 ([WideCharToMultiByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130.aspx)). Also, highly recommended read: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Or, leave it wide and just update your `Content-Type` header to include the `charset=utf-16` attribute instead: `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-16"`.  But, it is not common to use UTF-16 with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so the server might not be able to decode it correctly. UTF-8 is more commonly supported, so yes, you should convert your wide string to UTF-8 and then include the `charset=utf-8` attribute in the `Content-Type` header.